# Linear automorphisms with a single eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $GL(V)$ be the automorphism group of $V$. I need to find an automorphism of $V$ with only a single eigenvector for a bit of a proof I'm working on, but I can't think of any. Does anyone have a **hint** on how to construct one?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you mean it has a single one-dimensional eigenspace. If $v$ is an eigenvector so is $kv$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: an $n\times n$ triangular matrix $A$ with all coefficients on the diagonal equal to $\lambda\ne0$ (whatever number you want as eigenvalue), such that $A-\lambda I$ has rank…

Comment: I'm thinking it should have rank $n-1$, right? In the case where the remainder of the entries in the upper triangle should be 1, we get a matrix of full rank (ensuring it's an automorphism) but will only have as an eigenvector (0,0,...,0,1).

Comment: @walkar Yes: the dimension of the eigenspace relative to $\lambda$ is $n-\operatorname{rk}(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I should be able to use this in what I need.